# Understanding variable scope in given code

Tags: scope, lisp, elisp

I'm a beginner in Emacs lisp, so this is really a noob question. Let's say that I have to write a function that uses a loop to add 1 to each element of a numeric vector.

Here is the code I wrote (the comments indicate what I'm *trying* to do at each step):

```
(defun add-one (x)
  "Use a loop to add 1 to each element of list X"
  (let* ((res x) ; make a copy of X
         (counter 0)) ; set counter to 0
    (while (< counter (length x))
      ;; Replace each element of RES by adding 1:
      (setcar (nthcdr counter res) (1+ (car (nthcdr counter x))))
      (setq counter (1+ counter)))
    ;; Display result:
    (message "%s" res)))
```

But my code seems to be destructive for `x`, since several calls to the function do not produce the same result:

```
;; Define a list:
(setq mylist '(1 2 3 4))
;; Several calls to the function:
(add-one mylist) ; -> (2 3 4 5)
(add-one mylist) ; -> (3 4 5 6)
```

Here is my question: I don't understand why my code is destructive (I expected the result to be `(2 3 4 5)` at each execution). I know that `setcar` is destructive, but it is applied to a copy of `x`, not to `x` itself. So why is the result changing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let does not make a copy of anything, so this assigns the value referenced by the variable `x` to the variable `res`. Hence any changes to the list referenced by `res` also change the list referenced by `x`

`(let* ((res x) ; make a copy of X`

Comment: Thanks! Well, I think that this is what I really do not understand in Lisp programming (compared to other languages I'm used to).

If I understand well, when I declare a variable `x` with `let` (or `setq`) and give it the value of another variable `y`, then `x` and `y`become basically the same object, and they are linked "in both directions"? Any change made on `x` will dynamically affect `y`, and *vice versa*?

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of clarity:
Despite the fact you do not copy input list, your code is not at all lispy. Try this instead:

```
(mapcar '1+ '(1 2 3 4))
```